# Filter Array by date of last 12 months(year to date)

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, momentjs, lodash

I have an array that I want to filter out results based on a year (past year only) from todays date. I have lodash and momentjs at my disposal so imagine using these to help accomplish my goal. As below I only want to use .gameScore with a .reportDate within the last year.

My array looks like this... (so it should only return the first object as its within the year to date range)

```
0:{gameScore: "1", reportDate: "2018-05-09"} 
1:{gameScore: "3", reportDate: "2017-06-12"}
```

I am doing other things with the data that should come after the filter:

```
var result = _(observations)
.omitBy(x => x.gameScore === "NULL")
.map(observation => ({ ...observation, value: SCORES[observation.gameScore] }))
.value();
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: you mean filter only the dates of this year ?

Comment: A year from todays date e.g 27/06/2018 to 27/06/2017

Comment: The problem starts with having the dates as string. If they were timestamps or ISO dates, you could simply use array.filter() with a given min and max.

Comment: @TomRudgeYou can do it by by comparing respectively `years`, `months` then `days` to keep only the ones from the last year. Check [my **answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51061798/3669624) for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use **[`Array.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and filter dates that are relevant, by **comparing respectively** `years`, `months` **then** `days`.

```
var result = observations
  .filter(observation => {
    return (
        moment(observation.reportDate).year() == moment().subtract('years', 1).year() &&
        (moment(observation.reportDate).month() > moment().subtract('years', 1).month() ||
        moment(observation.reportDate).month() == moment().subtract('years', 1).month() &&
        moment(observation.reportDate).days() >= moment().subtract('years', 1).days())) 
          ||
        (moment(observation.reportDate).year() == moment().year() &&
        (moment(observation.reportDate).month() < moment().month() ||
        moment(observation.reportDate).month() == moment().month() &&
        moment(observation.reportDate).days() <= moment().days())
        );
  });
```

**Demo:**

```js
var observations = [{
    gameScore: "1",
    reportDate: "2018-05-09"
  },
  {
    gameScore: "3",
    reportDate: "2017-06-12"
  }
];

var result = observations
  .filter(observation => {
    return (
        moment(observation.reportDate).year() == moment().subtract('years', 1).year() &&
        (moment(observation.reportDate).month() > moment().subtract('years', 1).month() ||
        moment(observation.reportDate).month() == moment().subtract('years', 1).month() &&
        moment(observation.reportDate).days() >= moment().subtract('years', 1).days())) 
          ||
        (moment(observation.reportDate).year() == moment().year() &&
        (moment(observation.reportDate).month() < moment().month() ||
        moment(observation.reportDate).month() == moment().month() &&
        moment(observation.reportDate).days() <= moment().days())
        );
  });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP wanted last year, not previous year

Comment: @barbsan Yes, my bad I edited the answer to take into consideration year,month and day comparison.

Comment: This is only bring back data in 2017, it should only return 2018-05-09 as thats within the last year. 2017-06-12 was over a year ago

Comment: @TomRudge My bad, I inverses the conditions; I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks @chŝdk and all else that contributed - hope it helps other out too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `observations` contains those objects you can filter them like this:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setFullYear( date.getFullYear() - 1 );
observations.filter(x => {
    return new Date(x.reportDate) - date > 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using momentjs it would be something like this:

```
_.filter(observations, o=> moment().add(-12, "months").isSameOrBefore(moment(o.reportDate)))
```

or this:

```
_.filter(observations, o=> !moment().add(-1, "year").isAfter(moment(o.reportDate)))
```

Note that `isSameOrBefore` has been added in momentjs v2.11.0. Since v2.0.0 there are separate function `isSame` and `isBefore` or you can negate `isAfter`. See more in [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/).

```js
var observations = [
{gameScore: "1", reportDate: "2018-05-09"},
{gameScore: "3", reportDate: "2017-06-12"}
];

var result = _.filter(observations, o=> moment().add(-12, "months").isSameOrBefore(moment(o.reportDate)));

console.log(result);

result = _.filter(observations, o=> !moment().add(-1, "year").isAfter(moment(o.reportDate)));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.11.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get get the date of last year. And then filter on that

like

```js
var dates = [
{gameScore: "1", reportDate: "2018-05-09"},
{gameScore: "3", reportDate: "2017-06-12"}];

var date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1);
date.setHours(0,0,0,0)

var filteredDates = dates.filter( o=> new Date(o.reportDate) >= date);

console.log(filteredDates)
```

To get the date of last yeah you can simply subtract from from year using and then `.setFullYear` and then simply compare the dates

Answer (score 0):

First you'd have to get a `moment` object of your date, convert it to a unix timestamp and then compare it to the current time's timestamp.

```
var date = moment("29-06-1995").unix();
var current = moment().unix;
var difference = current - date;
```

Then you can see if the difference is larger than a year

```
if(difference >= 31556926) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

This condition will go in the callback for your `array.filter()`